# inspect element and wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-4.5.2

In two websites, created with wordpress, and using the same theme, after update wordpress to 4.5.2, the header menu disapeared.

But, if i use the "Inspect Element" Option, the header menu is displayed

And there is the cuestion: is posible using css to reproduce the function of "Inspect Element" to show the menu? And what is the process of "Inspect Element"?

Comment: You cannot make any changes live with inspect element. It is just for temporary use, so that you can apply the same in the live version.

Answer (score 0):

If you see it in inspect element then just copy paste the styles to style.css and see what happens